# Kendo UI AutoComplete as editor in grid - how to display selected value?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I do have a Kendoui grid in which I fill one column with the AutoComplete as editor:

```
{ title: "Desription", 
    field: 'description',
    editor: function(container, options) {
        var input = $("<input id='selecteditem' />");
        input.attr("name", options.field);
        input.appendTo(container);
        input.kendoAutoComplete({ 
            dataSource: dataSource, 
            dataTextField: "name"
        }); 
    },
    template: "#=name in description#",
    width: "300px"
}
```

where the aoutocomplete data comes from a database via php:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: { read: 
       { 
         url: "/cabinet/test/autocomplete/data.php", 
         dataType: "json" 
       }
});
```

and the php is the following:

```
$query = ('SELECT shipitem_id AS id, name, description, cat_id, lang_string FROM jml_mss_shipment_items');              

$link = mysql_pconnect($dbOptions['host'], $dbOptions['user'], $dbOptions['password']) or die ("Unable To Connect To Database Server");
mysql_select_db($dbOptions['database']) or die ("Unable To Connect To Database");

$arr = array();
$rs = mysql_query($query);
while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) { $arr[] = $obj; }

header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode($arr);
exit();
```

This works fine when I select the items but when I move on to the next row it leaves

```
[object Object]
```

in the cell.

I have tried everything to get the original value displayed, including the above template (which gives an error that description is undefined), without success.

What can I do to overcome this? It must be something simple!

Comment: Seems to be a problem related to the format of the received data. Did you check what comes out from the server when you open in the browser the URL `/cabinet/test/autocomplete/data.php`?

Comment: Yes, and I altered what is send to see whether it makes a difference, but no joy. If I stringify the `data` in my template I get `{"description":{"name":"sportswear"}}`. Therefore it seems that using description should work but I get an invalid error regarding description if I use that. It seems that description only becomes "known" after an autocomplete action. This error prevents the adding of new rows anyway.

Comment: What comes currently from the server in the `data.php` script is something like: `[{"name":"Cosmetic"},{"name":"Toys"}]`. Could this format cause my problem?

Comment: Yes, it is a problem. In the first case you say that `name` is inside `description` while in the second you say that you get an array of elements that have one field that is `name`. It is similar but not the same

Comment: I also get the same result when using `template: "#=name#"`. The field name is `description`, but if I change it to `name` then I end up with the same problem, i.e. `{"name":{"name":"sportswear"}}` when using stringify BUT I changed the template to `template: "#=name.name#"` and I use the field `name` and it works!!

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that either in the first case they are just { "name" : "sportswear" } or in the second case they are in an array as `[ { "description" : { "name" : "Cosmetic" } }, { "description" : { "name" : "Toys" } } ]`

Comment: Just another additional issue that I have. After selecting the required item from the dropdown list, I want to close the editor by pressing the enter key, but it doesn't. Is there something that I need to add somewhere to achieve this?

Comment: If you edit the original question and include the format of the data that you would like to use I might try to show you how to define the datasource and columns.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30404/discussion-between-jmarais-and-onabai)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you create a new row the row is created according your model definition in the DataSource. Since you are using nested objects (the field `description` is actually an `object` containing `name`) this is not created.

So you should check in your template that you have an actual value. Something like:

```
template: "#= (data.description ? data.description.name : '') #",
```

For the question of closing the autocomplete as soon as you hit enter, you need to invoke `closeCell` from the autocomplete `change` event. Something like:

```
{
    title   : "Description",
    field   : 'description',
    editor  : function (container, options) {
        var input = $("<input id='selecteditem' />");
        input.attr("name", options.field);
        input.appendTo(container);
        input.kendoAutoComplete({
            dataSource   : dataSource,
            dataTextField: "name",
            change       : function (e) {
                grid.closeCell();
            }
        });
    },
    template: "#= (data.description ? data.description.name : '') #",
    width   : "300px"
}
```

Check a complete running example here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/mpNuA/3/

Comment: I like your fiddle example but there is an weird behavior with it. If I type an  "S" and then exit the AutoComplete field without making a selection, I see undefined in the field. Even if I go back in and make a selection and exit the field, there is still an undefined value.

Comment: I am facing the same issue as described above by @AlanFisher. could you provide solution to this undefined issue? I am using kendo v2015.2.902

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with the Keno Autocomplete (= when selecting a value in an empty field Kendo will display [object Object]. When selecting a value in a populated cell Kendo will sometime display the correct value).

After a long and mighty struggle I found this attribute: valuePrimitive (see [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/autocomplete#configuration-valuePrimitive))

It seems that this attribute was added on Kendo Q2 2013. **It does NOT exist on Kendo Q1 2013**.

Once I added this attribute AND switched to Kendo Q2 2013 my application started working OK.

For the sake of completeness and since real-life examples of Kendo code are rare here is my full Kendo autocomplete editor function:

```
function productNameAutoCompleteEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input data-text-field="ContactBusinessName" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoAutoComplete({
            autoBind: false,
            serverFiltering: true,
            filter: "contains",
            ignoreCase: true,
            valuePrimitive: true,   //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            dataTextField: "ContactBusinessName",
            dataSource: {
                type: 'odata',
                serverFiltering: true,
                serverPaging: true,
                pageSize: 40,
                transport: {
                    read:
                        {
                            url: "/api/v1/AutoCompleteContacts",
                            dataType: "json"
                        },
                    parameterMap: function (options, type) {
                        var paramMap = kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap(options);
                        delete paramMap.$inlinecount; // <-- remove inlinecount parameter.
                        delete paramMap.$format; // <-- remove format parameter.
                        delete paramMap.$callback; // <-- remove format parameter.
                        return paramMap;
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    data: function (data) {                            
                        return data; // <-- The result is just the data, it doesn't need to be unpacked.
                    },
                    total: function (data) {
                        return data.length; // <-- The total items count is the data length, there is no .Count to unpack.
                    }
                }
            },
            select: function (e) {
                var item = e.item;
                var text = item.text();
                // Use the selected item or its text
            }
        });
}
```